# Crash during UICollectionViewCell reordering after Swift 3.0 migration

Tags: swift3, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I do have a strange issue in using the reorder feature in my app's UICollectionView. We have a custom layout which is implemented to show a decoration view. The collection view uses a flow based layout. When I move the first cell from its position to last cell position for reordering of the cells, the app crashes before it calls the collection view delegate's  `collectionView(moveItemAt: to)` method.

Attached the stack trace of this issue. You can see that crash is happening in the bridging between NSIndexPath and IndexPath. I am not sure why it is happening inside UIKit. Searching for this issue found that it appears to be bug inside UIKIt which got introduced in Swift 3.0. I tested my old build which was built before swift 3.0 migration and it works without any crashes.

Can someone tell me how can I fix this issue?

Related bugs links
[UICollectionView broken after Swift 3 migration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39621534/uicollectionview-broken-after-swift-3-migration)
https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-2103
https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-2417

[image]
[image]

```
func handleLongGesture(_ gesture: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {

    switch(gesture.state) {

    case UIGestureRecognizerState.began:
        if let movingPageIndexPath = collectionView.indexPathForItem(at: gesture.location(in: collectionView)) {
            collectionView.beginInteractiveMovementForItem(at: movingPageIndexPath)
        }

    case UIGestureRecognizerState.changed:
        collectionView.updateInteractiveMovementTargetPosition(gesture.location(in: collectionView))

    case UIGestureRecognizerState.ended:
        collectionView.endInteractiveMovement()

    default:
        collectionView.cancelInteractiveMovement()
    }
}
```

Comment: Add the code that you are currently trying.

Comment: Once the user ends dragging of cell and lifts his finger from the device, UIGestureRecognizerState.ended switch gets called which in turn calls collectionview(moveItemAt: to) API.

Comment: @NiravD : Do you know about this issue and possible solution?

Comment: Is your `handleLongGesture` method called? put break point and check that once because it is hard to predicate crash reason form this type of crash log.

Comment: Yes its being called.